# Specifying special/reserved characters in android textview xml

Tags: android, xml, special-characters

Hallo,

Anyone know how to specify 'special' or 'reserved' characters for a TextView object in the xml?

What I want to display in my text view is ?/? so I put:

```
android:text="?/?"
```

but although this displays correctly in the eclipse 'Graphical Layout' of the xml file, it gives an error:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '?/?')
```

I've tried using:

```
"&#63;&#47;&#63;"
```

but the error is the same.

TIA,

- Frink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the '?':

```
android:text="\?/\?"
```

Comment: Cheers, spot on! I thought I'd tried that, but maybe I did it on the / not the ?